# Installing software in Dropbox (or in a similar service) Will it work in other computers?

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to install software -not portable apps- in a Dropbox folder (in a folder of a similar service such as Google Drive, Copy, SkyDrive, etc) and expect it to **run correctly** in *any computer that access to that folder* (of course after files from the installation has been uploaded to the net)?

I wish to avoid installing software in my computer (in my local drive); I want to do it in the cloud. I would like to achieve one installation = software running in many computers.

My OS is Ubuntu.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This entirely depends on the software.  Some software is portable other software is not.  All the listed services requires the files in the cloud to also exist on your hdd.  If this is about saving storage space your idea won't work.

Comment: @Ramhound: I wish to avoid having to install the software in other computers. I would like to achieve one installation = software running in many computers.

Comment: As I indicate what you want entirely depends if the software is designed to beportable.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @techie007: I have many software. I do not think trying it is the best option.

Comment: Trying is showing effort, which keeps you from getting down-voted for "lack of research".  :)  We can't possibly speak to all software, and we have no idea what software you have in mind.  Why not try one or two of your primary ones?  If _ANY_ work, then the answer to your question is "Yes it's possible".

Comment: @techie007: You are right :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the application in questions relies on any data that is being kept in the Registry, it will not work on other computers that it has not been installed on, or at the very least had the Registry Keys added to.

If the application relies on data in AppData, user folders or other client-specific locations, they will not work without copying all the files, and hoping that you got them all.

In short, if it's a portable app, no problems. If it isn't, the majority of the time the answer is no.

Edit: Since this is Ubuntu, rather than Registry/AppData, you'll need to be concerned with Dependencies. Since you haven't installed the program on the target computer, and apt will be unaware of its existence, any dependencies you may need won't be pointed out to you.

Comment: Do this apply to Ubuntu (my OS) too?

Comment: @pablofiumara - Yes it does apply to Ubuntu.  You will have to be sure the dependencies are in the cloud also.

Comment: @tjennings: Thanks for your answer. How can I be sure the dependencies are in the cloud also?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the software you try to install. Some programs install registry keys, and without those registry keys your programs might not work on all computers.

Comment: Do this apply to Ubuntu (my OS) too?

Comment: Not on Ubuntu, I was referring to Windows. There might be something similar on Ubuntu, but I'm not familiar with any Linux distributions. I wouldn't recommend doing this. You should just install your software on each computer, if there aren't that many.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is great to hear a Windows's user point of view.